# total unique items

Tags: javascript, sqlite

I have an SQLite database and in it are stored, as an example:

```
COUNT  DESCRIPTION  SIZE
5      red boxes    5x5x20
3      blue boxes   8x8x8
3      red boxes    5x5x20
4      green panels 10x10
7      blue boxes   5x5x20
```

Is it possible to achieve a summary like:

```
8  red boxes    5x5x20
3  blue boxes   8x8x8
7  blue boxes   5x5x20
4  green panels 10x10
```

Comment: Please edit your question to make it more readible.

Comment: is that more readable?

Comment: yes, just group by description and size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(count) AS count, description, size
FROM table
GROUP BY description, size
ORDER BY count
```

`SUM` is an aggregating function combining several rows into one. The `GROUP BY` clause lists all fields that have to be the same so that rows are allowed to be combined (in your example, only two rows are combined into one).